# How can I enable Source Maps for Sass in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, google-chrome-devtools

According to this issue https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/pull/192 
`sass-rails` hasn't support for Sass 3.3 yet.

But it seems that [`sass-rails-source-maps`](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps) has been depending on Sass 3.3 since the very beginning. So is there a way to use this gem with `sass-rails`?

According to the readme with `sass-rails-source-maps`, Chrome dropped support of the Source Maps files from Sass older than version 3.3.

Does that mean there is no way of using Sass Source Maps with Chrome devtools now?

Comment: Did you mean to ask if there is any way to make **sass-rails** work with source maps in DevTools?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Yes, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 17):

There is a great new drop in replacement for sass-rails, which is not only faster, but also has the option to use inline source-maps.

Just add it to your Gemfile

```
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

and add the configuration

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.sass.inline_source_maps = true
```

Don't forget to restart your server, then you should see it working in the inspector:

[image: Source maps in Safari inspector]

You can find the repo here:
https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails

Comment: You can clearly see that the question is asking in context with sass-rails.  "Use something that's not sass-rails" would only be a valid answer if sass-rails didn't provide access to source maps.

Comment: @cimmanon I think you are missing the point here. The question states clearly "source maps for sass in rails". And the answer is currently the only way to achieve that. I can say that after trying all the other answers, they are deprecated. So by downvoting, you basically take away the chance for anybody who is looking for a solution to get it going. Thank you for your great community work!

Comment: I just tried this and still see the generated CSS at line number in the Chrome console style inspector instead of the SCSS line number. So I don't see any benefit.

Comment: @MSC You probably missed something.. Did you add the config option like described? Did you restart your server?

Comment: just note that is not compatible with `compass` for now

Comment: @Krisdigital - Can't get it to work. Removed gem and added new gem. Bundled. Added config inline source maps. Added inline comments. Stopped server. Cleared cache. Restarted server. Webconsole shows an application$fingerprinted.css and also a application.source.css.  Every element css reference points to a (among thousands) line in application.css (~40K lines of bootstrap).  Any hints? Would love to have this work the way I know you intend.  Thanks. - Jim

Comment: @codenoob Did you try with a simple case (not bootstrap)?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use source maps with Rails 4.1 in this way:

1. by using the beta of the sass-rails gem (5.0.0.beta1), which isn't always the safest thing to do, and by
2. adding the "compass-rails" ("2.0.1") and the "compass-rails-source-maps" ("0.0.8") gems. I don't use Compass in this particular project, but the compass-rails-source-maps gem needs the compass-rails gem (obviously), and it worked great for me.

I didn't have much luck with the sass-rails-source-maps gem, but I didn't spend a lot of time with it; perhaps it isn't compatible with the beta sass-rails gem, or something else I'm using.