# Source maps in Rails 4-5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, coffeescript

I was doing a search on how to use source maps for sass or coffescript on a rails 4 or rails 5 app.

However because I've found some links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180867/how-can-i-enable-source-maps-for-sass-in-rails-4) one that posted along time ago or others got confused me alot, so I 'd appreciate if you could give me some feedback on how to sort this properly.

Do I need to set up a gem for this? such as [this one](https://github.com/swrobel/sass-rails-source-maps) ?

Do I need to add these lines in my assets?

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=/assets/source_maps/application.css.scss.map */
//# sourceMappingURL=/assets/source_maps/app/assets/javascripts/notes.map
```

As I side note I use Firefox on Ubuntu (I'm saying that because there are some resources that talk specificlly for Chrome and I'm not entirely sure if same things could apply and in Firefox too)